# Way to save apache losgs with IP Info

Tags: linux, apache2, log-files, ubuntu-18.04, files

i use this command to live see apache logs:
sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log
I use a Ubuntu 18 VPS wich i have root access.
this logs are also saved to the access.log file true? (because when i search some string in the live mode i find some things that i do not see when i use CAT to see the access.log file)

My questions is: is there a way to FOR every log to find info of the IP and save to another file the HOSTNAME of that IP together with the log data?

Comment: `grep 127.0.0.1 /var/log/apache/access*.log` would look for 127.0.0.1 in access*.log you just need to use `>mynewlog` to redirect the output

Answer (score 0):

You can use one package from apache httpd bundle, named `logresolve`. With command like:

```
logresolve  < access.log > access.log.new
```

You can resolve the IPs from `access.log`. For more information you can check [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/logresolve.html).

If you want to extract only IPs you can use command like:

```
awk '{print $1} access.log|sort -u >IP_addresses
```